# Union Select nested queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing a query which needs to return all child entries (and their children etc...) under any given parent ID.

For example:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE parent_id IN

    (SELECT id
    FROM table
    WHERE parent_id IN

        (SELECT id
        FROM table
        WHERE parent_id IN

            (SELECT id
            FROM table
            WHERE code = 'A01')
        )
    )
```

As expected, this will only return a result set for the topmost `SELECT` query. I could write a `UNION SELECT` for each child level but that seems a tad clumsy...

Is there a way to add each individual result set from each nested query into my main set of results? Or should I take the clumsy option?

Comment: Which version of SQL? 2005 onwards you can use a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: sorry, I'm using sql server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is best solved with a recursive query.  A great way to perform recursive queries in SQL Server 2005 or later is to use [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT id, parent_id
    FROM [table]
    WHERE code = 'A01'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.id, t.parent_id
    FROM [table] t
        INNER JOIN cte 
            ON cte.id = t.parent_id
)
SELECT id 
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

On a side note... I'm not sure I like the idea of the table name being `table`.

Comment: :D Thank you. I made up the names of the tables and columns etc by the way for example purposes ;)